# How do you modify achievements on Google Play Games?

Tags: android, mobile, google-play-games, achievements

We're developing a game which has achievements and while we haven't released it yet, we did publish for Beta testing and have also published Game Services for that app for testing purposes.

We now realise that we need to tick the incremental option on a few achievements but we can't as "this field cannot be changed after publishing". I have unpublished the game and service but this never allows us to edit.

We then thought we could delete the achievement and set it up again, but there is no Delete or Reset option available.

Is this a case of the unpublish setting taking a while to propogate on Google Play or is what we need to do impossible?

I never published to Google Play public so it would be frustrating if we weren't able to fix this :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you are correct.  There is no way to change those attributes or delete a published achievement.  So the alternatives are:

1. Create a new achievement with the configuration you want to have,
   and leave the existing one there (maybe achievement for starting the
   incremental achievement?).
2. Create a new game configuration.  This
   means all the game state will be reset from the player's
   perspective.

In the future, I don't think you need to publish the game to start testing.  You can Alpha and Beta test with named testers, and make changes to the game configuration.  Then once the game is perfect, publish it.  More information on staged rollouts: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the official Google documentation for [Editing the achievement](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#editing_an_achievement).

***Note: Once an achievement is published, its initial state (hidden or revealed) and its type (incremental or standard) is fixed and cannot be changed.***

**Undoing an edit**

If you decide you don't like your current achievement and want to go back to your achievement the way it was before, select Revert from the drop-down list in the Google Play Developer Console, and all of your achievements will revert back to the previously published version.

**Deleting an achievement**

Once your achievement has been published, it cannot be deleted.

You can only delete an achievement in a pre-published state by clicking the button labeled Delete at the bottom of the form for that achievement.

**Resetting an achievement**

You can only reset player progress data for your draft achievements.

To reset achievements in the Google Play Developer Console, click the button labeled Reset achievement progress at the bottom of the form for that event.
To reset achievement data programmatically, call the Management API Achievements methods.